# Software centre and Evolution think I am offline using WICD to make wireless connection

Tags: 11.10, network-manager, wicd

I upgraded to 11.10 yesterday. I use WICD to make the wireless connection because I have never managed to get network manager to make a wireless connection on any computer I have installed it on. But since 11.10 both Evolution and software centre are convinced I am offline even though I have a functional connection (I am using wifi now and both are reporting me offline, which I clearly am not).

I am using an MSI WIND clone Advent 4211 B netbook. Network manager has never worked on this computer for wifi. WICD can make connection about 30% time (often returns BAD PASSWORD, first few attempts). XP of course works fine to make wifi connection. I have a

I am happy to supply more information I just do not know what information might help. I have reported a bug against evolution

Comment: Finally found out how to get network manager to run. The command is nm-applet for any one else who has trouble. network manager works! I have never seen it working before. it is quite exciting. I have filled a bug on evolution not seeing the network when WICD is used.

Answer (score 2):

OP has answered the question in a comment;

> Finally found out how to get network manager to run. The command is
>   `nm-applet` for any one else who has trouble. network manager works! I
>   have never seen it working before. it is quite exciting. I have filled
>   a bug on evolution not seeing the network when WICD is used.